# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Amazon Linux 2 - How to set a custom NodeCommand

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

[Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2 - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

According to the docs, the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs` namespace is no longer supported and the new way to set `NodeCommand` is to "Use a Procfile or the scripts keyword in a package.json file to specify the start script.".

I've never dealt with Procfiles and the part "the scripts keyword in a package.json file" isn't very clear, are they going to execute the scripts in order, until something sticks or what?

Did anyone figure out how exactly to set a custom NodeCommand in Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: For anyone using Amazon's sample node app as a reference, it still contains references to the out-dated documentation, which you should ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [script](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-package-json-guide#scripts) option in your `package.json`. For example, if you start sample node.js application that EB provides, the file is:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Elastic-Beanstalk-Sample-App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

#### Update

[Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.container.html) have example how to use **Procfile**:

> You can add a Procfile to your source bundle to specify the command that starts your application, as the following example shows. This **feature replaces the legacy NodeCommand option** in the aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs namespace.

```
web: node index.js
```

> When you don't provide a Procfile, Elastic Beanstalk runs npm start if you provide a package.json file. If you don't provide that either, Elastic Beanstalk looks for the file app.js or server.js, in this order, and runs it.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to tell it to use something different than `npm start`?

Like I mentioned, in the original Amazon Linux, you could use `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs` namespace and set `NodeCommand` or change it from the config dashboard (Configuration -> Software -> Node command).

Comment: @Buzzkill Yo can use `Procfile`, if yo don't want `package.json`. I updated an answer